# Raspberries are 85% water, raspberry jam is 30% water, and sugar contains no water. What weight of jam can I make with 2.8 kg of raspberries?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, percentages

By weight, raspberries are 85% water, raspberry jam is 30% water, and sugar contains no water. I make raspberry jam by mixing equal weights of raspberries and sugar and then boiling them to evaporate off some of the water.

What weight of jam can I make with 2.8 kg of raspberries?

If $x$ is the final amount of jam produced, then final amount of water $w = 0.30x$

Final amount of water $w$ is some percentage $n$ of the water in raspberries $= (2.8*0.85)n\\ ⇒ 0.30x = 2.38n$

Final amount of jam = amount of raspberries without water + amount of water from raspberries + sugar.

so, $x = 2.8*0.15 + 2.38n + 2.8\\ ⇒ x = 2.38n + 3.22$

Solving, $x = 2.38 * \frac{0.30}{2.38}x + 3.22\\⇒x = 4.6$

So **4.6 kg** of jam can be produced from 2.8kg of raspberries.

Is that correct and using an efficient technique?

I mention "efficient technique" because i often spend a lot of time going round in circles trying to relate facts in algebra.

Comment: Your calculation is correct. I've started by calculate the amount of jam one gets from 1kg raspberries: The jam consists of the "pure" 150g raspberries with 1000g of sugar and $x$g of water.  Now $x/(150+1000+x)=0.3$ from which $x=345/0.7$g, that makes $3450/7$g.  So we get $$150+3450/7+1000 =11500/7\text{g}$$ grams jam from 1kg of raspberries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your method seems correct, but it can be done more straightforwardly.

You have $2.8$ kg of rasperries, of which $0.85\cdot2.8 = 2.38$ kg is water, and the remaining $2.8-2.38=0.42$ kg is non-water.

After adding the $2.8$ kg of sugar, you still have have $2.38$ kg water, but now have $0.42+2.8=3.22$ kg of non-water.

After evaporating some water to make the jam, the water is $30\%$ of the whole, so the non-water must be $70\%$ of the whole amount of jam. If $x$ is the whole amount of jam, $3.22$ kg is $70\%$ of $x$, then we get $0.70\ x = 3.22$, or $x=4.6$ kg of jam.

Comment: Ah yes, the non-water fact in this case makes the solution much more succinct and easier to follow. Comes with natural ability or lots of practice i guess. Thanks